# WHERE clause and LEFT JOIN in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    EnrollmentID, MarketID 
FROM 
    Contracts AS CO
LEFT JOIN 
    Customers AS C ON C.EnrollmentID = CO.BatchID AND MarketID = 'AB'
WHERE 
    C.EnrollmentID IS NULL
```

Here, I have a question that in this query is it possible that the query will verify data for `MarketID = 'AB'` in left join because as per `WHERE` condition?

I am getting result of `EnrollmentIDs` and `MarketIDs` are all `NULL`.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  It is unclear from the description what you are trying to do.

Comment: A where in a left join will make it into an inner join

Comment: You are using left join and filter result by null in table on right side of left join. Of course you will get NULLs in EnrollmentID, MarketID  if they are from right table in left join

Comment: Since you are using LEFT JOIN you get all contracts despite there is not matching customer. On not matching rows EnrollmentID and MarketID are NULL.

Comment: Please, tell us which result you are looking for.

Comment: Which table has MarketID ?

Answer (score 0):

***Note: The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all the rows from the left table (Contracts ), even if there are no matches in the right table (Customers ).***

Now, if you want to select right table column and there are no matching data in the right table ,like.

```
SELECT CO.EnrollmentID, CO.MarketID ,C.Some_col
FROM Contracts AS CO
LEFT JOIN Customers AS C ON C.EnrollmentID = CO.BatchID
```

so, *C.Some_col* column will get all the null value for no matching rows in the right table.i think this is the reason why you are getting the null value for 
MarketIDs  and EnrollmentIDs.

hope, this help you.